# Jquery slide toggle not showing content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on More Information, it changes to Less Information but the content under doesn't slide toggle in.

https://jsfiddle.net/n1gLn63y/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").hide();
  $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
    var txt = $(".content").is(':visible') ? 'More Information' : 'Less Information';
    $(".toggle").text(txt);
    $(".toggle").toggleClass('active');
    $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(450);
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

**EDIT:** Include relevant html from fiddle

```
<div class="description">

  <div class="descriptionTitle">
    <p class="Title"> KITAI / SELF-DIAGNOSIS </p>
    <p class="toggle">More Information</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.toggle` is the **last** element in it's parent container, there is no `next()` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).next('.content').slideToggle(450);`

that element do not have next element with `content` class, But its parent have,So:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").hide();
  $(".toggle").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var txt = $(".content").is(':visible') ? 'More Information' : 'Less Information';
    $(".toggle").text(txt);
    $(".toggle").toggleClass('active');

    $(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle(450);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n1gLn63y/2/

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).next` doesn't find `.content` as it's not a sibling.

`.next` only finds elements that have the same parent (siblings).

Try:

```
$(this).closest(".descriptionTitle").next('.content').slideToggle(450);
```

or rearrange your html

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/officert/h7w40494/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").hide();
  $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
    var txt = $(".content").is(':visible') ? 'More Information' : 'Less   Information';
  $(".toggle").text(txt);
  $(".toggle").toggleClass('active');
  $('.content').slideToggle(450); //this was the problem
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

where you were doing `$(this).next('.content').slideToggle(450);`
was the issue. In this case $(this).next('.content') means get the sibling element with class `.content`, but the element with `.content` is not a sibling.

Comment: `$('.content').slideToggle(450);` this will toggle all elements with `content` class

Comment: Yea I used this because he had already used $('.content') and figured he know the repercussions of doing so.